# zref: Read out first and last reference page per page

Tags: cross-referencing, ref, zref

I have some paragraph numbers on most of my pages. 
I want to write "(1-3)" in the head if the current page contains the paragraph numbers 1,2,3.

Is it possible to read out the first and the last label page per page (with zref? I do not know this package really.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, paper=a5, 
twoside, numbers=enddot,headsepline,plainheadsepline,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{marginnote}

% \usepackage[savepos,totpages,titleref,dotfill,counter,user]{zref} % ?

% Paragraph numbers
\newcounter{parnumber}
\newcommand\parnum[1][\theparnumber]{%
\leavevmode%
\refstepcounter{parnumber}%
\marginnote{\theparnumber\label{pn:#1}}% Label
}

% Layout
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}[]
\ohead*{\marginnote{(xxx-yyy)}% range of parnums
\ifstr{\headmark}{}{\rightbotmark}{\headmark}% titles in head
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Page: The Range of parnums should be (1-3) = (xxx-yyy)}
\parnum[TPy]
Theorem of Pythagoras \par
\parnum
\blindtext  \par

Text without parnum.

\parnum Text.

\chapter{Next Page: The Range of parnums should be (4-5)=(xxx-yyy)}
\parnum Text.

\parnum[mylabel] Text.

\chapter{Only one parnum on this page: The Range of parnums should be (6)=(xxx-yyy)}
\parnum Text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is a job for `zref`. It's easy to do if you are ready to live without the chapter and section titles in headings (my opinion is that it is naturally a job for marks). If you want to keep them, it seems harder to me—unless there is some way to set additional, independent marks that behave like TeX's `\firstmark` and `\botmark`.

Comment: @frougon Thanks. OK, I am sorry: I do not say -  I had some solutions with marks, but this does not work in special kinds (like the parnum is inside a multicol environment). So I ask myself: Is it possible with zref?

Comment: Ah... bad news. I could be mistaken, but I don't see how `zref` could help. You can get the *current* value of a property, but I don't see how that would help you to get the first value put on the current page—à la `\firstmark`, which you need.

Comment: @frougon Mmh, maybe with a good if-methode... But I do not know the package zref well enough.

Comment: @frougon It is doable and easy with zref: create numbered \zlabel which store beside the page also the parnum and at begin document loop through the labels to get the minimum and maximum parnum value by page.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Seems you're right, stupid me! I wasn't thinking of using a combination as you said, and two passes. I believe one would have to redefine `\zref@newlabel` in order to intercept labels starting, for instance, with a special prefix, and from there compute the “first parnum” and “last parnum” for each page with such zlabel(s). Or do you have a better idea?

Comment: @frougon Why redefining \zref@newlabel? You only need to issue \zlabel{@pn:\the\value{parnumber}}  every time the counter is changed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unless I'm mistaken, we are talking about different things? `\zlabel` would be done in the document where a numbered paragraph starts, but the thing I was talking about was how to compute first parnum and last parnum for a given page, which would be done `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: @frougon as I wrote: simply loop through all `@pn:N`-labels, get their page number and sort the stuff.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But this requires knowing the last `N` value? You write it to the `aux` file manually? Because I don't know any zref command for iterating over all labels matching a given regexp (say), or simply starting with a given prefix.

Comment: @frougon you can always set a last label to store the last number in the aux. Or simply stop if the next label doesn't exist ... And the looping should be done with expl3 or so.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Right, I think this would work using `\zref@ifrefundefined` to detect the end of such labels. This assumes though that 1) parnums are strictly monotonic (let's say, strictly increasing) and 2) there are no holes in there (otherwise, the dumb algorithm would wrongly detect the end of parnums upon finding the first “hole”). Due to a complicated health situation, I won't be able to work on it right now, but if no one else does meanwhile, I could probably have something working later today or (hopefully) tomorrow.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I forgot to ask: the OP [said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496223/zref-read-out-first-and-last-reference-page-per-page?noredirect=1#comment1252885_496223) he couldn't use marks because of “parnum inside a multicol environment” (I suppose this means situations where the marks don't migrate to the main vertical list). AFAICT, both zlabels (`\write`) and `\mark` are implemented as whatsits; are we sure that zlabels always get written to the aux file regardless of how deep they are embedded in TeX lists (horizontal, inner vertical, etc.)? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Almost ready. @cis What would you like to see when there is no parnum on a given page?

Comment: @frougon Very good question. For example: If page 5 has only the parnum '7' and the next three pages (6,7,8) has no new parnum -  there should still be '7' written. (This way, I saw it on a book from 1963.)

Comment: Answering [my own question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496223/zref-read-out-first-and-last-reference-page-per-page/496393?noredirect=1#comment1252984_496223): contrary to `\openout`, `\closeout` and `\write`, `\mark` doesn't seem to be implemented as a whatsit. According to page 280 of the TeXbook, a non-`\immediate` `\write` is “performed (...) during any `\shipout` that applies to [the enclosing] list, unless the list is part of a box inside leaders.” This explains why my code works fine even for parnums inside a `multicols` environment itself inside a `minipage`.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this makes this `zref`-based method technically superior to any method based on marks, except for the fact that it requires two compilation runs like any `\label`/`\ref`-like thing.

Comment: @frougon  You could create a package based on this methode. If you want ;)

Comment: @cis Yes, that would be a good candidate, I believe. I need to see improvements in the things I mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496223/zref-read-out-first-and-last-reference-page-per-page?noredirect=1#comment1252950_496223) before being really comfortable with this idea, but I'll keep it in mind... (note that the code is [already](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8261/73317) licensed under the LPPL 1.2+, plus whatever TeX.SE guarantees for anything posted here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do what you want (thanks to Ulrike Fischer for her useful comments!). I used `(n--p)` style for ranges, but switching to `(n-p)` style or something similar if you prefer is trivial (just look at `\__cis_output_parnum_range:nn`: this is the function doing the formatting of parnum info; it should be fairly easy to modify for this kind of change).

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, paper=a5, twoside, numbers=enddot,
               headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{zref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% ****************************************************************************
% *             LaTeX3 bindings to macros from the zref package              *
% ****************************************************************************

% Extract prop #2 recorded for ref cis-parnum-label-#1 (#1 corresponds to a
% parnum)
\cs_new:Npn \cis_extract_prop:nn #1#2
  {
    % \zref@extract is expandable
    \use:c { zref@extract } { cis-parnum-label-#1 } {#2}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cis_extract_prop:nn { V }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cis_ref_used:n #1
  {
    \use:c { zref@refused } { cis-parnum-label-#1 }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cis_ref_used:n { V }

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \cis_if_parnum_ref_defined:n #1 { p }
  {
    % \zref@ifrefundefined is expandable
    \use:c { zref@ifrefundefined } { cis-parnum-label-#1 }
      { \prg_return_false: }
      { \prg_return_true: }
  }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \cis_if_parnum_ref_defined:n { V } { p }

% ****************************************************************************
% *                Main code for generation of parnum ranges                 *
% ****************************************************************************

% Most important variable: in the \AtBeginDocument hook, we are going to fill
% it to give the parnum range for each page that has at least one parnum. Keys
% in this property list are page numbers (in decimal notation); values have
% the form '{first}{last}' (without quotes). E.g., {2}{5} or {6}{6}. If a page
% contains no parnum at all, the property list will have no key equal to the
% corresponding page number.
\prop_new:N \g_cis_parnums_for_page_prop

\int_new:N \l__cis_fpfep_parnum_int
\int_new:N \l__cis_fpfep_page_in_ref_int
\int_new:N \l__cis_fpfep_last_page_seen_int
\int_new:N \l__cis_fpfep_first_parnum_for_page_int
\int_new:N \l__cis_fpfep_last_parnum_for_page_int

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_compare:nNnF { VN }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_compare:nNnF { VNV }

% #1: first labelled parnum in document (if any)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__cis_find_parnums_for_each_page:n #1
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l__cis_fpfep_parnum_int {#1} % next parnum to examine
    \int_set:Nn \l__cis_fpfep_last_page_seen_int { -1000 } % sentinel value

    \bool_while_do:nn
      { \cis_if_parnum_ref_defined_p:V \l__cis_fpfep_parnum_int }
      {
        % Get the page for parnum \l__cis_fpfep_parnum_int
        \int_set:Nn \l__cis_fpfep_page_in_ref_int
          { \cis_extract_prop:Vn \l__cis_fpfep_parnum_int { page } }
        \cis_ref_used:V \l__cis_fpfep_parnum_int

        \int_compare:VNVF
          \l__cis_fpfep_last_page_seen_int = \l__cis_fpfep_page_in_ref_int
          {
            % The parnum corresponding to the currently examined ref is on a
            % different page than the previously-examined parnum, therefore
            % we now have all the info for the last seen page -> store it.
            \__cis_store_parnums_if_real_page:VVV
              \l__cis_fpfep_last_page_seen_int
              \l__cis_fpfep_first_parnum_for_page_int
              \l__cis_fpfep_last_parnum_for_page_int

            \int_set_eq:NN \l__cis_fpfep_first_parnum_for_page_int
                           \l__cis_fpfep_parnum_int
          }

        % Will be overwritten if there are more parnums on the same page
        \int_set_eq:NN \l__cis_fpfep_last_parnum_for_page_int
                       \l__cis_fpfep_parnum_int
        \int_set_eq:NN \l__cis_fpfep_last_page_seen_int
                       \l__cis_fpfep_page_in_ref_int
        \int_incr:N \l__cis_fpfep_parnum_int
      }

    % Store info for the last page containing a labelled parnum
    \__cis_store_parnums_if_real_page:VVV
      \l__cis_fpfep_last_page_seen_int
      \l__cis_fpfep_first_parnum_for_page_int
      \l__cis_fpfep_last_parnum_for_page_int
  }

% #1: page number or sentinel value (-1000) meaning “do nothing”
% #2: first parnum on this page
% #3: last parnum on this page
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__cis_store_parnums_if_real_page:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \int_compare:nNnF {#1} = { -1000 }
      {
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g_cis_parnums_for_page_prop {#1} { {#2} {#3} }
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__cis_store_parnums_if_real_page:nnn { VVV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__cis_output_parnum_range:nn { VV }

\tl_new:N \g__cis_oprfp_first_parnum_tl
\tl_new:N \g__cis_oprfp_last_parnum_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cis_output_parnums_range_for_page:n #1
  {
    \prop_get:NnNTF \g_cis_parnums_for_page_prop {#1} \l_tmpa_tl
      {
        \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { } \l_tmpa_tl
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_tl

        \tl_gset_eq:NN \g__cis_oprfp_first_parnum_tl \l_tmpa_tl
        \tl_gset_eq:NN \g__cis_oprfp_last_parnum_tl \l_tmpb_tl
        \__cis_output_parnum_range:VV \g__cis_oprfp_first_parnum_tl
                                      \g__cis_oprfp_last_parnum_tl
      }
      {
        % In case there is no parnum at all on a page, the OP wants the page
        % header to hold only the last parnum seen (not the last parnum info,
        % i.e.: he wants only a number, not a range). Hence "last, last"
        % instead of "first, last" here:
        \__cis_output_parnum_range:VV \g__cis_oprfp_last_parnum_tl
                                      \g__cis_oprfp_last_parnum_tl
      }
  }

% Write formatted information for the specified parnum range.
%
% #1: first parnum of range
% #2: last parnum of range
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__cis_output_parnum_range:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_if_eq:nnTF {#1} {#2}
      {
        \tl_if_blank:nF {#1} { (#1) }
      }
      {
        (#1--#2)
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cis_output_parnums_range_for_page:n { x }

% Fully expands the argument (which should be a page number)
\NewDocumentCommand \parnumrangeinpage { m }
  {
    \cis_output_parnums_range_for_page:x {#1}
  }

% 1 is the number of the first parnum to consider as possibly existing in the
% document. \__cis_find_parnums_for_each_page:n looks for refs corresponding
% to parnums 1, 2, ... The smallest integer in this scanning process for which
% no ref is found in the .aux file is considered to be one past the last
% parnum.
\AtBeginDocument { \__cis_find_parnums_for_each_page:n { 1 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter

\zref@newlist{cisparnumlist}
\zref@addprop{cisparnumlist}{page}

% Paragraph numbers. Must be strictly increasing, and the numbering should
% have no holes.
\newcounter{parnumber}

\newcommand*\parnum[1][]{%
  \leavevmode
  \refstepcounter{parnumber}%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{\label{#1}}% regular LaTeX label for the numbered paragraph
  \marginnote{%
    \theparnumber
    % Set our special zref label for parnums. From the set of all such labels,
    % we can deduce in the \AtBeginDocument hook the parnum range for each
    % page.
    \zref@labelbylist{cis-parnum-label-\the\value{parnumber}}%
                     {cisparnumlist}}%
}

\makeatother

% Allow easy on/off switching of parnum info in headers
\newtoggle{parnumsinheader}

\newcommand*{\parnumsinheaderon}{\toggletrue{parnumsinheader}}
\newcommand*{\parnumsinheaderoff}{\togglefalse{parnumsinheader}}

\parnumsinheaderon              % Show parnum info in headers by default

% Set up the page headers
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead*{%
  \iftoggle{parnumsinheader}{%
    \marginnote{\parnumrangeinpage{\thepage}}% range of parnums
  }{}%
  \ifstr{\headmark}{}{\rightbotmark}{\headmark}% chapter or section title, etc.
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Three parnums here}

\parnum[TPy]
Theorem of Pythagoras \par
\parnum
\blindtext  \par

Text without parnum.

\parnum Text.

The theorem of Pythagoras corresponds to parnum~\ref{TPy} on
page~\pageref{TPy}.

\chapter{Two parnums here}

\parnum Text.

\parnum[mylabel] Text.

\chapter{Only one parnum here}

\parnum Text.

\newpage % Test repeating of last parnum info when there is no parnum on the
         % current page.
\chapter{Test with parnums deeply embedded in \TeX\ lists}

\noindent
{\centering
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \parnum Text.

  \lipsum[1-3]

  \parnum Text.
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
}
\newpage
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]

---

[image: Page 2]

---

[image: Page 3]

---

[image: Page 4]

---

[image: Page 5]

---

[image: Page 6]

Comment: Wow, that's very cool!
I noticed something else: the last page should only show '(8)' instead of '(7-8)'. Because '(8)' is the last given parnum.
I wish I could correct that myself. But that absolutely exceeds my LaTeX level of knowledge.

Comment: Well, from [your commment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496223/zref-read-out-first-and-last-reference-page-per-page/496393#comment1253165_496223), I had understood that on pages with no parnum at all, you wanted the header to show the last parnum *info,* instead of just the last parnum. This is fixed, see the latest version of my answer.

Comment: Wow, very good! That helps me a lot. I would not have believed that the task has that volume.

Comment: The main work is to find the (first parnum, last parnum) pair for each page. Once that's done, the rest is essentially formatting. It would have been easier with marks such as `\firstmark` and `\botmark`—they were designed for that—but that wasn't the question and LaTeX already uses them for running heads, which you do use. There might be some other way with `titleps` though, if this works with the KOMA classes (but it's out of the question scope).

Comment: A mark-solution is given here: https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/24932/koma-skript-unterscheidungsmethode-fur-mark-kennnummern    But obviously that does not work in all cases. So I think, a ref-solution is better for a book with ~500-1000 pages or something else.

Comment: (no time to look at this link now, sorry) Concerning my answer, I have fixed broken indentation in the main function (`\__cis_find_parnums_for_each_page:n`), simplified it a little bit (there was a redundant `\int_set_eq:NN`) and expanded a comment to ease understanding; so, you should probably fetch the code again. The behavior should be strictly unchanged, though.

Comment: Ah ok. Especially good is that parnums appear only from the first call (parnum> 0), so for example not yet in toc or on previous pages.
I have already tested that.

Comment: Yes, this is the purpose of the `\tl_if_blank:VF` test in `\__cis_output_parnum_range:NN` :-) (`\tl_new:N` initializes `\g__cis_oprfp_first_parnum_tl` and `\g__cis_oprfp_last_parnum_tl` as empty).

Comment: I added a toggle (`parnumsinheader`) and simple commands (`\parnumsinheaderon` and `\parnumsinheaderoff`) to allow easy on/off switching of parnum info in headers. This should cover the basic needs. Also removed a stray `[]` after your `\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}`, and improved a few comments.

Comment: I modified `\__cis_output_parnum_range` to be more elegant and easier to read (now natively `:nn` with a `:VV` variant, instead of natively `:NN`). I believe it's all perfect now. :)

Comment: Very good! With your help, I have my Layout complete.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Out of curiosity, are you typesetting an old book, writing a new one... or something else (no problem if you don't want to answer)?

Comment: The reference method with the parnums I have from a linguistic textbook from 1963.
This is very convenient and reads very pleasant; because you can always look up in the right place.

Otherwise, I write a book with geometric content and a lot of TikZ. And in that I really wanted to include the parnums.